# Projector 1080p image is a different size depending on the source

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, images, hdmi, projector

I have a Benq W1070 projector.  I was using it with my Ubuntu PC, and now I'm using it with my Windows PC, connected via an HDMI cable.

Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit has a Gigabyte ATI HD4850 graphics card and OS bundled drivers.

Windows 7 64-bit has an ASUS ATI HD7850 graphics card and Catalyst drivers.

I've set the image position and size using the test pattern.  When sending a 1920 x 1080 image to the projector from Ubuntu the image I get fills the entire projected area, so it's the same size as the test image.

However, the same resolution image from the Windows 7 PC makes a smaller image on the projector.  I see the entire image, but it's just scaled down.  I'm pretty sure that this is wasting bulb power as well as reducing the resolution of the image that I'm seeing.

I've tried googling for solutions but funnily enough when you search for projector image size you get discussions of zooming & throw distance, which I'm already pretty well educated on.  This is an issue of the projector not using the entire pixel matrix that should be available to me.  Anyone asking why I can't just zoom the image to get the size that I want will be directed to the following sentence:  that is not the problem that I am trying to solve.

So the questions are:

- Why is this happening?
- How do I make the Windows image fill the entire pixel matrix?

Comment: I have found the overscan adjustment on the projector, which makes it better, but not perfect.  I'm still baffled as to why one source's image is treated properly but not the other one, when they are the same resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this issue has been resolved, but I thought I'd just say it because it seems no one has yet. I was having this exact problem until I found a solution browsing the web. This can be resolved by using the Catalyst Control Center. There should be a scaling option under "My Digital Flat-Panels" and selecting scaling options. Good luck.

Here is the source: http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/58879-3-benq-full-screen

Comment: That was it, amazing, after months someone just comes along with the answer.  I guess that'll teach me for not installing Catalyst, I probably could have found the answer if I just had that program available back in freaking October last year.  My display is much crisper now, I can tell the different now that the pixels are actually 1 to 1.  Ugh, why was that the default setting?  Bizarre.  Thank you.